# Scope to be used for editting Python Variables' syntax in Default Color Scheme's .tmTheme file

Tags: python, variables, syntax, sublimetext2, highlighting

I think there are more sophisticated ways to do change syntax highlighting, which I am unable to follow very at this time. Hence I tried, what I thought was a simpler way i.e. by modifying one of the default color scheme's .tmTheme (located in Packages/Color Scheme - Default).

For example, in the Monokai.tmTheme, if I added

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key> 
        <string>PyVariable</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>source.python meta.item-access.python</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FD971F</string>
       </dict>
   </dict>
```

I was able to modify the color coding for Python syntax that came under the Scope 'source.python meta.item-access.python'.

However, for variables that I declare in Python, I get no specialized Scope when I use the Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P keys; I only see 'python.source'. If use this Scope in the .tmTheme file, then the syntax for everything that comes under python.source, that was not previously coded white, changes.

I realize I may be trying a method that will not work, but I thought I would give it a try. Perhaps the more sophisticated methods, where I have to "generate a JSON file" etc, is what I have to do.

Thank you for your patience with a newbie to sophisticated text editors :)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to check out a theme with nearly all the Python scopes covered, have a look at my [Neon Theme](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-sublime-theme), which is also available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation). Basically, you're doing the right thing by trying to edit the `.tmTheme` file in order to get at the scopes. The problem with Python is that there is no single way of saying whether an identifier is a variable, as there is no syntax like `$my_var` in PHP, for example. `my_var` in Python could be a a string variable, the name of a function or class (albeit a poorly named one), a list, a dict, a tuple... etc. So, in ST2, variables are just `source.python` and can't be individually highlighted.

The good news is that a bunch of other stuff *can* be highlighted, such as function definitions (they come after the keyword `def`), function invocations (they have `()` parens after them), different sorts of strings (single-quoted, double-quoted, raw, bitstreams, Unicode, etc.), and a bunch of other stuff. If you're planning on working with themes and scopes more, I recommend getting the [ScopeHunter](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) plugin, as it's easier to get at the individual scopes when they show up in a panel as opposed to briefly appearing on the status bar.